# How do I append a view to the node body in custom module?

Tags: nodes, 8

In Drupal 7, we could do the following within a hook_node_view:

```
$node->content['nodehierarchy_children'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'nodehierarchy_children_embed',
  '#nodehierarchy_view' => $node->nh_children_view,
  '#nodehierarchy_view_display' => @$node->nh_children_view_display,
  '#nodehierarchy_view_args' => $arguments,
);
```

Then in the hook_theme:

```
function nodehierarchy_views_theme() {
  return array(
    'nodehierarchy_children_embed' => array(
      'render element' => 'element',
    ),
  );
}
```

Finally we have the theme function:

```
function theme_nodehierarchy_children_embed($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $display = $element['#nodehierarchy_view_display'];
  $arguments = $element['#nodehierarchy_view_args'];
  return $view->execute_display($display, $arguments);
}
```

How do I accomplish the above in Drupal 8? I'd like the implementation to be Drupal 9 compatible, so ideally I don't want to use depreciated functions etc.

I mean should I attempt to somehow override node.html.twig and provide it with a render array using something similar to:

```
$view = views::getView($node->nh_children_view)
$build['nodehierarchy_children_embed'] = $view->buildRenderable($display,$arguments);
```

I think if someone could provide the functions and general methodology, I could fill in the coding portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For later versions of Drupal 8, the above no longer worked, so I had to change it to the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view().
 */
function mymodule_node_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $node, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode){
  // Get the arguments to send to the view. 
  $arguments = ...;
  if ($view = Views::getView('my_view')) {
    $view->setDisplay($display);
    $view->setArguments($arguments);
    $build['some_random_name'] = $view->render();
    // Set the weight high to append the view to the end of the body or omit it otherwise.
    $build['some_random_name']['#weight'] = 1001;
  }
}
```

Comment: I gives this error `Warning: Illegal string offset '#weight'`

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out that the hook_node_view was all that was needed, but I don't know why it didn't work the first time:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view().
 */
function mymodule_node_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $node, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode){
  // Get the arguments to send to the view. 
  $arguments = ...;
  if ($view = Views::getView('my_view')) {
    $display = ...
    $build['some_name'] = $view->buildRenderable($display,$arguments);
    $body = $node->get('body')->value;
    $node->set('body')->value = $body.render($build['some_name']);
  }
}
```